# How to fix: fatal: Invalid back reference

Tags: git, grep

I'm trying to find occurrences of three repeated characters, other than period or dash, in a git repo. Can somebody explain why this does not work:

```
$ git grep -n "([^.-])\1{2}"
fatal: command line, '([^.-])\1{2}': Invalid back reference
```

Why the `\1` is not a valid back reference to first capture group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a capture group, you need to backslash the parentheses. You also need to backslash the curly brackets to make them into a quantifier:

```
git grep -n "\([^.-]\)\1\{2\}"
```

Or, use extended or Perl-compatible regular expressions that use literal parentheses and curly brackets for capturing and quantifying, respectively:

```
git grep -nE "([^.-])\1{2}"
git grep -nP "([^.-])\1{2}"
```

Comment: The reason git says "Invalid back reference" is because `\1` matches the POSIX back reference syntax but plain `(` and `)` do not match the expected syntax. The POSIX Basic Regular Expressions or BRE syntax considers plain `(` and `)` as verbatim text and only considers `\(` and `\)` as the capture group delimiters. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html for details.